# Multilingual android apps issue

Tags: android

Currently i am using this code to change the language of my app, but it only work well in one activity but not whole activities, how do i make it to change the language for whole activities?[Second problem is when i select one of the language from spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ajLS.jpg)   & [After that the apptheme become black&white theme..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yNCn.jpg)

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_language);
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {

            if (pos == 1) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected 中文简体", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("zh");
            } else if (pos == 2) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected Hindi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("hi");
            } else if (pos == 3) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("en");
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
}




public void setLocale(String lang) {
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    if (!conf.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {
        conf.locale = new Locale(lang);
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, LanguageActivity.class);
        startActivity(refresh);
        finish();
    }
}
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // refresh your views here
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
}
```

Comment: Try change Resources res = getResources(); => getApplicationContext().getResources().

Comment: @tinysunlight Sir, you mean change it to Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();  ? if yes, it still no fix my second problem, the apptheme auto change to black&white theme

Comment: res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm); => res.updateConfiguration(conf,null);

Comment: @tinysunlight sir, it still no fix my problem..

Answer (score 1):

You can use a static method inside the Application class to set the default locale, and call it from every class in your app:

Application:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      ...
    }

    public static void setLocale(String lang){
        Locale defaultLocation;
        defaultLocation = new Locale(land);
        Locale.setDefault(defaultLocation);
    }

}
```

Activity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_language);
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int pos, long id) {

            if (pos == 1) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected 中文简体", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                MyApplication.setLocale("zh");
            } else if (pos == 2) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected Hindi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                MyApplication.setLocale("hi");
            } else if (pos == 3) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                MyApplication.setLocale("en");
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: For your code, i try to combine it in java but it fail, i have to change the "extend Application" to "extend Activity", and after that i compile the app, It did show " You have selected Language", but it don't change any language for my apps

Comment: Sorry , maybe i don't understand what you taught me, hope you don't mind it.

Comment: Every android app has an Application. This class is the base class for those who need to maintain global application state. This application is declared in the manifest file.

Comment: The attributes and methods in Application are visible in the hole application. You just need to call the static method "MyApplication.setLocale("en");". I don't know if it is the right way to do that, but I think it work.

Comment: Sorry did you mean that i have to create a new class for the "MyApplication" and the code for Activity is replace for my current activity code? Sorry i am really new in Android..

Comment: If the Activity code you provided is combine with the class MyApplication, it's not working due to the onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in Application cannot be applied to android.os.Bundle, and also "setContentView" and "findViewById". Once i change to extend Activity, the code is error-free but  my apps is no function for change the language except pop out the msg "You have select the language i choose"

Comment: ok, forget my answer, try another thing: below the line "conf.locale = new Locale(lang)", put this line "Locale.setDefault(conf.locale)" and tell me if it  works.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work..can let me send you the project so you can what's the wrong in the code?

Comment: i used your method, but it no function on MyApplication.setLocale("en"); It did show pop message but it doesn't change the language